# Android, going from OpenGL-ES loop to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, opengl-es

I'm new in android programming and i have an issue with going from the onDraw loop to an activity with a normal view.

I want to open an activity that shows the score when you lose the game.

Thanks.